# Prevent users from calling protected endpoints + OAuth2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

For learning purposes, I am developing a REST API + Angular 4 application using OAuth2.

There are some protected endpoints which can only be called by authenticated users. Let's take an endpoint to update user's profile as an example:

POST
/users/{user_id}

Logged in users will be able to update their own profiles by going to the Update Profile screen which in the background will call /users/{user_id} sending the payload with the new information and the access token.

How do we prevent a malicious user from calling the same endpoint to update other user's profiles?

A user with id 1 should be able to call /users/1 but not /users/2?

Is this something that can be done with OAuth? or maybe I am misunderstanding something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with the typical REST-style API (i.e. ID of the user profile to update is sent with request) you must add some additional check to the server side. The access token which is used to authenticate the user contains her/his identity which should result in a respective `Principal` object in the request scope. You must check whether the user represented by this principal is really authorized to update the user profile given with the ID in the request.

For example, you could first load the profile with the given ID from the database and then check if the username equals the one of the principal. This can also be done by Spring Security `PreAuthorize` annotations and a little bit of SpEL magic in its argument.

Alternative way: Move away from your REST-style API and simply provide an endpoint `/update-profile` (or similar naming) which does not require the user ID as part of the URL. Then you simply take the identity of the user given with the access token and update the respective profile in the database. So the user can only update profiles which she/he can obtain access token for. - The downside is that you will not be able to allow some super user or admin to update any arbitrary profile in this setup.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There is a cool stuff called guards in angular. Heres link for docs: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score -1):

Please read about Spring Security with Oauth2. Since you are implementing both backend and frontend, password grant type would be appropriate. Oauth 2.0 specification talks about it here: [password grant type (aka, Resource Owner Password Credentials)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)  and [check this link as well](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/).

To answer your question, in password grant type - username and password is used to get access token. Every request comes from frontend would need to pass that access token. A secured endpoint will check if the access token is valid and is issued against the same user or not.